# $\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx<\infty$ if $\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|^2e^xdx<\infty$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have the following problem:
There is given an Borel measurable function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, which fulfills
$\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|^2e^xdx<\infty$.
I should show, that $\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx<\infty$.

There is a hint given, that $x\mapsto e^{-x}$is a probability density on $[0,\infty)$. And that I already know a random variable with finite second moment under this measure. I should observe the first moment, but I do not know, which random variable is meant.

I do not know, what I should do. I know the nth moments of the exponential distribution but will i need them?
I would be very thankful, if someone can tell me, how I can interpret the hint and than I would go on trying to solve this problem, but now I am stuck.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Remember Cauchy Swartz?
$$\int |a(x)b(x)|dx \leq \left( \int a(x)^2 dx \right)^{1/2} \left( \int b(x)^2 dx \right)^{1/2}$$
Now choose $a(x)=f(x) e^{x/2}$ and $a(x)b(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: I thought about CauchySchwarz, but was not sure how to apply. Thank you, I will try it with this hint.

Comment: Perhaps $a(x)=f(x)e^{x/2}$ is a better choice?

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now I only have to show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}>\infty$. Is it enough to calculate the integral and say it is 1. But I think it doesn't work, because I need to observe random variables? Here I have again the problem, that I do not understand the given hint..

Comment: @mickep That is a good point. Thanks

Comment: It is enough to show that $\int_0^\infty e^{-x} dx$ evaluates to a finite number. Your other statement may or may not help but it is not needed based on my approach.

Comment: ok, thank you!!!! In retrospect the exercise was easier than expectet, but I did not get it on my own